# Http request in constructor doesn't change attribute value

Tags: angularjs

I've got a problem with this constructor:

```
 function ApiManager() {
    this.api= new ApiInterface();
    this.apiVersion = -1;

    this.api.getVersion()
        .then(function(version) {
            console.log(version); // "1.0"
            this.apiVersion = version;
            console.log(this.apiVersion); // "1.0"
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Couldn't find API version.")
        });
}
ApiManager.prototype = {
    getApiVersion: function() {
        return this.apiVersion; // "-1"
    }
};
```

I have an object with the attribute apiVersion, which is initialized with the value -1. After that an HTTP request is executed by the ApiInterface and assigns apiVersion the value 1.0. Later I call the function getApiVersion and it returns the old value -1.

I'm new to AngularJS and probably it's a silly rookie mistake, but I don't see what I've got wrong.

Comment: In your `ApiManager` function, try adding `var that = this;` on the first line and replace all of `this` references to `that`. See if it works.

Comment: You need to realize that promises are used because of asynchronism. That means that the line `this.apiVersion = version;` is executed long after the constructor has returned and, given the behavior you're observing, probably long after getApiVersion() has been called by the caller. A bit like if you sent a letter to a friend, then phoned him immediately after and asked "how many letters have you received from me?". The answer will be 0. getApiVersion() should not return a number. It should return a promise. Oh, and @SinaGh is absolutely right, too.

Comment: Thank you, both answers work great. I tried the promise variant and posted the result below. Perhaps you can tell me if I got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the Promises/A+ Spec says about the `this` keyword inside `.then` functions:

> That is, in strict mode `this` will be `undefined` inside of them; in sloppy mode, it will be the global object.

-- [Promises/A+ Spec -- Note 3.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-69)

So in your code, you need to explicitly bind instead of using the `this` keyword.

```
function ApiManager() {
    this.api= new ApiInterface();
    this.apiVersion = -1;

    //bind 'this' keyword to a var
    var vm = this;

    this.api.getVersion()
        .then(function(version) {
            console.log(version); // "1.0"
            //use that binding
            vm.apiVersion = version;
            console.log(vm.apiVersion); // "1.0"
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Couldn't find API version.")
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the job. (:

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the version with the promise and this is the result:

```
function ApiManager() {
    this.api= new ApiInterface();
    this.apiVersion = api.getVersion();
}

ApiManager.prototype = {
    getApiVersion: function() {
        return this.apiVersion;
    }
};
```

The ApiInterface returns a promise in the getVersion method.

```
getVersion: function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: myUrl;
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data.jsonapi.version;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return $q.reject(response.data);
        });
    },
```

Later on, I use it this way in my controller:

```
    $scope.printApiVersion = function () {
    var promise = manager.getApiVersion();
    promise.then(function(version) {
        console.log(version);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Couldn't retrieve API version.")
    });
}
```

This works great for me, but I don't know if it is considered good style.

Comment: Returning a promise and **chaining** from a promise is the better strategy. BTW, it should be `promise.then` not `p.then`. Also you don't need `$q.reject`. To **chain** an error from a `.then` or `.catch` method, just `throw` it. ie `throw response.status;`.